# importing timestamps + data from mysql to python and plotting time-series

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have a mysql table that I want to access and extract data from. The table is structured as seen here:

| Id | datestamp  | timestamp | bloodSugar | carbohydrates | insuline |

|  1 | 2013-08-05 | 18:28:17  |              6.7 |            76 |      6.6 |

**NB:** timestamp entries are generated using CURTIME()
**NB2:** Please excuse the horrible table--I would have posted an image, but don't have enough rep points to do so yet :(

I am trying to extract the timestamp and the bloodSugar values in order to plot a time-series with: time (HH:MM) on the x-axis, and bloodSugar-value on the y-axis. But I'm running into some issues...

**PROBLEM:** When fetching the data into a list in python the timestamps appear as datetime.timedelta(0, 58753) entries. I want these in HH:MM so that I can plot the data against them.

**QUESTION:** is there a way to simply re-format the timedelta into a HH:MM format? If this is not possible then please advise on how I could work around this (e.g. use another fetch technique with mysqldb, or replace CURTIME() with something else, etc.).

**Disclaimer:** I'm a noob, looking to learn, so please provide as through an explanation as you can. Thanks!!

code:

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates
import datetime

con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'testuser', 'test623', 'test');
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    #importing data into a list for analysis
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Diabetes")

    rows = cur.fetchall()

    data = []
    for row in rows:
        data.append(row)

    A = data

    d = [a[1] for a in A]
    t = [a[2] for a in A]
    b = [a[3] for a in A]
    c = [a[4] for a in A]
    novo = [a[5] for a in A] 

    #here is my attempt at trying to reformat the time-entries... But doesn't work..
    formatted_time = []    
    for delta_time in t:
        hours, remainder = divmod(delta_time[1], 3600)  
        minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)   

        duration_formatted = '%s:%s:%s' % (hours, minutes, seconds)
        formatted_time.append(duration_formatted)
print formatted_time


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot_date(t, b)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have bunches of timestamps stored as two disjoint columns called datestamp and timestamp. You didn't tell us the data types of those columns. (Keep in mind that `TIMESTAMP` is a MySQL reserved word, and thus a pretty poor choice for a column name.)

Best practice for this sort of data is to combine date and time into a single column of type `DATETIME`.  You might call it obstime (for observation time) or some such thing.  You can populate this field with the `NOW()` function.

If this information will relate to multiple health-care facilities, you may want to deal with timezones.  But that's another set of questions.

You can rewrite your MySQL query to combine your datestamp and timestamp columns into a single `DATETIME` column.   Try this to retrieve `DATETIME` values from your table

```
  SELECT id, bloodsugar, carbohydrates, insuline,
         CAST(CONCAT(`datestamp`, ' ', `timestamp`) AS DATETIME) obstime
    FROM Diabetes
   ORDER BY id
```

I am not sure from your question what hh:mm information you want.  Do you want elapsed time in hh:mm since the first measurement? If you're charting this stuff, maybe you want the observations in hh:mm:ss since the first measurement.  Let's work this one out.

This query gives you the first measurement -- the first in time.

```
    SELECT MIN(CAST(CONCAT(`datestamp`, ' ', `timestamp`) AS DATETIME)) firstobstime
      FROM Diabetes
```

You can join that query to your other one like so.

```
   ...
  FROM Diabetes AS d
  JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(CAST(CONCAT(`datestamp`, ' ', `timestamp`) AS DATETIME)) firstobstime
      FROM Diabetes
  ) AS f
```

This join doesn't need any `ON` clause; the second part of the join only yields one row.

So, then you can get a list of observations by minute since the beginning like so.

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(CAST(CONCAT(d.`datestamp`, ' ', d.`timestamp`) AS DATETIME),
                d.firstobstime) AS obstimeoffset
         d.bloodsugar, d.carbohydrates, d.insuline
  FROM Diabetes AS d
  JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(CAST(CONCAT(`datestamp`, ' ', `timestamp`) AS DATETIME)) firstobstime
      FROM Diabetes
       ) AS f        
 ORDER BY obstimeoffset
```

I think that's what you want.

Pro tip: Avoid `SELECT *` in queries in programs. It makes your programs break when you add columns to your table.

Another pro tip: combine dates and times in `DATETIME` columns.

A third pro tip:  I don't see any patient_id or experiment_id or any such thing in your table. As you've designed it, it's suitable for one patient and one series of observations. You may wish to make it more general. That's a much better approach than adding another table for each patient or experiment.